# Prisma nested "Where" with "OR" operator returns nothing

Tags: where-clause, prisma, prisma2, or-operator

Adding "OR" inside nested "where" returns nothing.

Removing "OR" inside nested "where" returns the results.

What's the issue?

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe replace your screenshot with a code block please? Moreover, could you provide the related prisma.schema models definition?

Comment: `schema.prisma` contains 500 lines.

also, not sure this query will help since it's 70 lines long. the only thing that changes is the "OR", which shouldn't influence the data returned, but for some reason - it does.

is this a known issue with nested "OR" not returning any data?

Comment: I've just tested again, same result. I think `take` or `skip` may be influencing it when "where" is nested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might arise from the query value being potentially undefined.
Using undefined as a value in a filter essentially tells Prisma Client you have decided not to define a filter for that column. In such cases, each Prisma operator behaves differently when no filters are defined:

- `OR` will return empty list.
- `AND` return all items.
- `NOT` return all items.

By commenting out the `OR` operator, you effectively applied the AND operator, resulting that returned all items.

For additional details refer to this page: [The effect of null and undefined on conditionals](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/null-and-undefined#the-effect-of-null-and-undefined-on-conditionals)